# Why "compress images using MRC" is always grey in ABBYY FineReader?

Tags: ocr

Does anybody using ABBYY FineReader 12 here? I found the "compress images using MRC" in "save" tab and "pdf" subtab is always grey and cannot be selected.

[image]

What is wrong? [According to documentation](https://abbyy.technology/en:features:ocr:pdf_mrc_export), MRC will result much greater compression. But why it is always grey?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be disabled when the document color mode is set to black & white rather than full color.